# Double await when invoke async lambda via Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, async-await, dispatcher

```
private async Task<T> LoadForm(WebControlAsync browser, Uri url)
{ ... }

var forms = await await _dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () => await LoadForm(browser, form.Url));
```

I don't understand why I have to use two `await`'s here to get `T` in `forms`? So it looks as `InvokeAsync` returns `Task<Task<T>>`. But when I invoke synchronous method like this:

```
var forms = await _dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => FillForm(forms, url));
```

it requires only single `await`. So the cause seems to be async lambda. I understand that if I write it this way:

```
var forms = await await _dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => LoadForm(browser, form.Url));
```

then the return type of `LoadForm` is `Task<T>` and `InvokeAsync` returns `Task<lambda return type>` so it indeed would be `Task<Task<T>>`. But when a `Task` method is `await`'ed, isn't it "unwraps" the actual return type from `Task`? So if I write:

```
var forms = await LoadForm(browser, form.Url);
```

`forms` would be `T`, not `Task<T>`. Why the same isn't happen in async lambda?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've answered your own question. `InvokeAsync` returns a `Task<T>` where `T` is the return type of the `Func<TResult>` delegate supplied to it. When you use an async lambda, you are no longer dealing with `Func<TResult>`, but instead `Func<Task<TResult>>`.

The reason you think that unwrapping should happen automatically is probably due to using `Task.Run` in the past. It should be noted, however, that `Task.Run` has an overload which accepts a `Func<T>` and returns a `Task<T>`, and an overload which accepts a `Func<Task<T>>`, and *still* returns `Task<T>`, so you take this unwrapping which is happening for you behind the covers for granted. This, however, does not apply in your case.

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is similar to `Task.Factory.StartNew` in this regard. It does not have an overload which would specifically deal with `Func<Task<TResult>>`, so you're stuck with unwrapping "manually".

Thing is, think about whether you really need `InvokeAsync` in your scenario. It won't give you much outside of scenarios where the dispatcher thread is overloaded with work. The `Task` which it returns will generally complete immediately (without awaiting the `Task` created by your `async` lambda) and just give you one more layer of wrapping to deal with. `LoadForm` is already `async` so you might as well just use `Dispatcher.Invoke` which will fire off your `async` lambda on the correct `SynchronizationContext` and ultimately return the task that you want to await, or, if you know that your `LoadForm` will always be called with the right `SynchronizationContext` (that is, on the UI thread), omit the dispatcher calls altogether and just let `async/await` do its thing.

Comment: I knew I did something wrong. :) Indeed there is no need in `InvokeAsync` in this case, `Invoke` will do what I want (I still need it because `LoadForm` will called from non-UI thread). Thanks!

Comment: @AlekseyShubin, what you did wasn't wrong in the true sense of the word. It just leads to slightly unconventional syntax that's harder to wrap your head around. When you absolutely cannot wait for the dispatcher thread to kick off your `FillForm` task via `Invoke` (which itself is a blocking operation that can take time if your dispatcher is busy), using `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is a valid choice, even if it does lead to funny syntax by forcing you to use a double `await` or `Unwrap` when combined with `async` (or simply `Task`-returning) delegates.